# Update SQL table from Python

Tags: postgresql

so, I have this list of values I will like to upload their data into a column named numbers on a table in sql (pgAdmin4). address is another column on the same table, I am using it to set the WHERE condition.

```
lst = ['34.1', '45.3', '57.5'] # few values for simplicity sake

for i in lst: 
    edit_tab = """UPDATE table_name SET numbers=%s WHERE address=%s;"""
    cur.execute(edit_tab, i['numbers'])

db.commit()
```

I constantly get error message and have tweaked to no end, and with new code above, I get the below error message

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

any help please? Note: this same code runs fine in Postgresql

Alternatively: I tried the inserting option as with the code below and constantly getting a syntax error. Now, a little more confused.

```
for i in lst:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO table_name (numbers) VALUES (%s);""")    
db.commit()
```

and below is the error message

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to cur.execute takes the query and an iterable.  There's something not quite right about the code you gave because i['numbers'] doesn't exist, it's just a list.  However, I can guess about the error you are getting.

Remember that in python, strings are also iterables, so I am guessing that in effect, you are trying to do this:

```
cur.execute(edit_tab, '34.1')
```

So, psycopg2 is trying to find placeholders for 3, 4, ., and 1.  Give it an iterable of two objects instead:

```
lst = ['34.1', '45.3', '57.5'] # few values for simplicity sake

for i in lst: 
    edit_tab = """UPDATE table_name SET numbers=%s WHERE address=%s;"""
    cur.execute(edit_tab, [i, address]) # Not sure what address should be

db.commit()
```

As mentioned in the code, I'm not sure what address should be, but this should give you the general idea on how to fix this.

Edit: 
Your added example doesn't work because you aren't passing any values.  Try something like this instead:

```
for i in lst:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO table_name (numbers) VALUES (%s);""", [i])    
db.commit()
```

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, thanks for taking the time, please see edits on my question to answer to your queries. Also, can you please clarify what you mean by an itterable of one object? still learning and new to this.

Comment: Sorry, that should have said two objects.  It's still unclear what you are trying to do because there are still too many errors in your code.  The line you added does not work because you aren't passing any values.  I'll update my answer to what I think it should be, though.

Comment: I am trying to take values I have in a list in python, and insert them into rows or  update rows in a column on a table in sql.  hopefully this helps, I look forward to your feedback.

Comment: Does my updated answer help?  The example at the end should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried yours,  and it worked, except just one row was updated. I understand the %s allows for formatting, not sure why the iteration worked just for the last row as it updated only the last row. And for the insert option, not sure why I have a syntax error as it looks ok to me.

Comment: For the insert, you didn't give it a value, so psycopg2 didn't try any string substitution, passed on the %s to postgres, where it threw an error.  For the update, it will just update the rows where address = whatever your address is.  Since that's not in the code you show, I can't comment further on that.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, your response on the insert option made me realise I did not have a link between the tables I was trying to update so, I created a DataFrame complete with all the info in python and updated sql ... again thanks for your help